# Fetching and displaying data from my webserver

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sdk

I currently have the following table cells setup:

[image: iPhone App]

I have the app getting information from a webserver the webserver returns data like this:

> 42739;Biology;A very long assignment that has to be cut short due to size;Due in 2 hours

How would you guys take that information and parse it into a usable datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Say your webservice results are stored in a string called myString, I would split the data into an array.

```
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Comment: How would you store the data.. The data is going to change frequently and doesnt really have to be stored for long.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by long? Is it to be stored only while the application is running, or do you want to store it in a file, like a local cache? For storing data and having it persistent in your application I would use CoreData. Makes it clean and easy to change the data model if the web service data change in the future.